# NSTextField rec'd focus?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield

How can I know when an NSTextField has rec'd focus?

Is there a delegate method that will tell me when the user has clicked the mouse in (or otherwise selected) my NSTextField?

thanks

tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass NSTextField and override `-becomeFirstResponder`.

Comment: Thanks Mike -- I was hoping/guessing that the NSTextField might send out a notification when it became the first responder.

Comment: Mike, `-becomeFirstResponder` of `NSTextField` [isn't available since Mac OS X v10.5](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html).

Comment: Deprecation ≠ "isn't available".  Also, `becomeFirstResponder` is declared in `NSResponder`; what the deprecation is saying is that it's not OK to *call* this method. Subclassing it is fine.